# Android Calculate distance in px between list items in recycler view

Tags: list, distance, items

Hello I want to calculate the distance between items of my list to be able to enlarge another divider view height according to the list items height (for example : in list item from position 0-to 5 get the height in px to enlarge the vertical divider height and so on)
I'm using java thnx in advance

I'm still figuring it out